# Is any Spin box control available for JQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there any Spin-box control for JQuery Mobile. I found nothing in Demo section. Which would be the best way to have one?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10167232/165674

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slider that allows the user to choose a value from a range by swiping the slider:

```
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/forms/forms-slider.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a spinner plugin at http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-Spinbox/ which is a basic spinner that just increases/decreases the value in the field. There are no min, max, or stepping options.