# Has anyone implemented jQuery Mobile Add (+/-) Button Number Incrementers?

Tags: forms, jquery-mobile, widget, spinner

This seems like a "must have" form input for a mobile ui framework, but jQuery Mobile doesn't seem to have one.

Has anyone implemented a nice looking number Spinner form input that works well with the other jquery mobile form inputs?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for the same... Have you found something like the picture above yet? The JQM "number" control isn't very fat-finger-friendly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably well after the fact, but: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-Spinbox/ - based pretty much on what you show above, respects jQM themeing, min/max values.

Comment: Nice work! Did you make this recently? I couldn't find it from your homepage.

Comment: Yes, just yesterday actually.  I needed a simpler plugin for a howto I am working on, this seemed to kill two birds. (http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-Plugin/ fwiw.  Still a little rough in places)

Comment: I asked on your forum, but figured I would ask here to be safe, is there an easy way to make it stack vertically?

Answer (score 3):

It's not exactly the same but an `input` with `type="number"` should give you an input field with two small buttons at the right (up & down).

You can check it [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/forms/textinputs).

Comment: On mobile it doesn't give you the two arrows.

Answer (score 1):

No just the slider input so far.

Answer (score 1):

Found this: http://css-tricks.com/number-increment-buttons/

Comment: Those are hideous.

Answer (score 0):

```
<i onclick="qty('plus');" class="fa fa-plus c_pointer"></i>
<input type="text" id="prdqty" name="qty" value="1" placeholder="1">
<i onclick="qty('minus');" class="fa fa-minus c_pointer"></i>



function qty(val){
pqty = $('#prdqty').val();
if (val == "plus") {
      var newVal = parseFloat(pqty) + 1;
    } else {
    if (pqty > 1) {
      var newVal = parseFloat(pqty) - 1;
    } else {
      newVal = 1;
    }
}
$('#prdqty').val(newVal);
}
```