# jQuery Mobile: number input and plus/minus buttons inline

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there a possibility to have a number input with minus-button on the left and plus-button on the right? Or maybe also -- ++ to change value in bigger steps.

I know that I'm not the first one asking this but:
[This](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-Spinbox/) solution is not displaying correctly in the first turn and jQuery-Mobile-Stepper-Widget from Github (can't post another link because I'm new) does not work with current version of jQuery Mobile.

The result should look like the screenshot in this question: [Has anyone implemented jQuery Mobile Add (+/-) Button Number Incrementers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167232/has-anyone-implemented-jquery-mobile-add-button-number-incrementers) respectively horizontal grouped buttons in jQuery Mobile

Any ideas or new snippets, working with current version of jQuery mobile?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Looks like the CSS is messed up on spinbox - the buttons still work, they just are in the wrong place.  working on it.

Comment: CSS updated.  Fwiw, spinbox is part of a larger (not even close to finished) project meant to be a how-to for writing jQM plugins - it's not really that mature, but I did update enough for it too look right again.

Comment: Thanks! But on Firefox (Desktop) the alignment of the buttons with the input was not pixel-perfect. I had to add a padding-top and padding-bottom:
padding-top:7.5px; padding-bottom:9.5px
or
0.45em and 0.6em

I've added this on line 42 of the jqm-spinbox.js
`w.d.input.css({'width':'40px','padding-top':'0.45em', 'padding-bottom':'0.6em'});`

On the Android Simulator the plus and minus buttons are not displayed at all. Why this?

Comment: [Here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/Number/) are several +/- number spinners.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a hint, the rest is purely *CSS* job and extra *JS* codes to control the value, e.g. maximum, minimum...etc.

**HTML**

```
 <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
   <button id="plus" data-inline="true">+</button>
   <input type="text" id="number" value="0" disabled="disabled" />
   <button id="minus" data-inline="true">-</button>
 </div>
```

**Code**

```
$('#plus').unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
    var value = $('#number').val();
    value++;
    $('#number').val(value);
});

$('#minus').unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
    var value = $('#number').val();
    value--;
    $('#number').val(value);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/zAWpZ/)

Answer (score 0):

In jQM the **input type number** does the most of the magic you want

```
<input type="number" name="number" value="0"/>
```

If you require more fancy styling you have to follow Omar's code

Comment: For me type="number" looks exactly the same as type="text" (Firefox 19, IE 10, Android using PhoneGap). So either I'm doing something wrong with jQM or this is more a browser thing than jQM. [html5 input types](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
<i onclick="qty('plus');" class="fa fa-plus c_pointer"></i>
<input type="text" id="prdqty" name="qty" value="1" placeholder="1">
<i onclick="qty('minus');" class="fa fa-minus c_pointer"></i>
function qty(val){
pqty = $('#prdqty').val();
if (val == "plus") {
  var newVal = parseFloat(pqty) + 1;
} else {
if (pqty > 1) {
  var newVal = parseFloat(pqty) - 1;
} else {
  newVal = 1;
}
}
$('#prdqty').val(newVal);
}
```